# Adobe Acrobat Pro PDF - textbox positioning

Tags: pdf, adobe, acrobat

I am creating a new fillable PDF in Acrobat Pro XI.  I added a textbox near the top of the page.  When I go into the textbox properties, the position appears like it's measuring from the bottom of the page.  so instead of saying the textbox is at 1", it's more like 10".  Is this default behavior for PDF's to measure from the bottom, and is there any way to change it?

Comment: You are pretty free to position the origin of the coordinate system anywhere you like in PDF pages, simply use an appropriate MediaBox or CropBox. Applications processing the PDFs, on the other hand, might have their own ideas how best to indicate the position. Thus, your question should probably be whether that is the default behavior .of Adobe Acrobat, not PDF.

Comment: it's just silly when your designing a PDF in adobe, the rulers that are displayed originate at the top left, but the positioning for text box is measured from the bottom left, making it interesting to say the least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all likelihood Adobe Acrobat is just following PDF convention. While it feels more natural to us - humans (at least on many places) to read from left to right and top to bottom, PDF uses a different coordinate system.

On PDF pages the origin of the page is at the bottom left corner. The x-axis points to the right and the y-axis points up. So a point near the bottom left of the page will be close to (0, 0), a point near the top left of the page will be closer to (0, page height).

Comment: *On PDF pages the origin of the page is at the bottom left corner.* - that's the case very often but it can actually be anywhere.

Comment: I didn't understand your comment on the OP's original question either in that regards, can you explain what you mean by that? I know the different matrices play a part but I have trouble placing your comment. If you can clarify I'll be happy to extend my answer.

Comment: As you know the origin (0,0) may be anywhere on a PDF page, simply choose the **CropBox** or **MediaBox** accordingly, no need to use matrices. The lower left merely is convention.